# Problem with reading data from '-v7.3' mat file using C++

Tags: c++, hdf5, mat

I tried to read the .mat file with -v7.3 in C++. As the .mat file with version -7.3 is the same as the hdf5 file, I try to read the mat file with the hdf5 API. I able to open group, reference, and the dataset. I also able to read the dataset with struct, int, double, or character array format.

But I see one dataset show its name as a class type. But I don't know how I read it. I attached an image for better understanding.

[image]

"error" field shows the value of a class type name. When I open it in matlab it shows like the below picture -

[image]

I also try a compound data type to read it. But I can not able to read. Can you suggest me any way to read the data from -v7.3 mat file in C++?

Comment: Can you post more details about the compound that you are trying to read? Eventually, it would be great if could you provide the hdf5 file containing this compound so that we can better debug the issue.

Comment: sorry, the file is confidential. So it is not possible to share it with you.

Comment: Ok - Can you run `h5dump` with this hdf5 file and post the result containing only the information about the structure of the compound? Like this, confidentially of the data is preserved.